# Como convertir un QlineEdit de Pyqt5 en float para usarlos luego en una ecuacion matematica?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Entiendo que si ya he asignado el QlineEdit a una varible quiero convertirlo esa en un float para luego usarlo en una ecuacion matematica

```
self.resSTD = QLineEdit(self)
self.resSTD.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Atlanta", 12))
self.resSTD.move(50,50)
self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.resSTD,1,1)

x = self.resSTD.text()
x1= float(x)
print(x1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema realmente no es ¿cómo? sino ¿cuándo?. Tu código es correcto pero veamos lo que hace:

- `x = self.resSTD.text()` ésto crea un a variable local llamada `x` y le asigna el **texto (`str`) que tiene tu `QLineEdit` en ese instante**.
- `x1= float(x)` convierte el valor asociado a la variable `x` en `float` y lo asigna a la variable `x1`. Es decir, contendrá el valor del `QLineEdit` como `float` en ese instante.

La clave es "en ese instante", si éste código lo tienes en el inicializador como parece obtendrá el texto en el momento de inicializar la clase que será una cadena vacía. **Debes hacer ésto cada vez que quieras leer el contenido del QLineEdit**.

Un ejemplo completo en el que se usa un botón para realizar la operación:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ventana(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(317, 220)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)

        self.line_ingresar = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_ingresar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 113, 32))
        self.line_ingresar.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator())

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("² =", self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 20, 61, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.label.setFont(font)

        self.line_resultado = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_resultado.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 50, 113, 32))
        self.line_resultado.setReadOnly(True)

        self.btn_calcular = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Calcular", self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_calcular.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 100, 88, 34))
        self.btn_calcular.clicked.connect(self.calcular)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot() 
    def calcular(self):
        num_str = self.line_ingresar.text()
        if not num_str:
            self.line_resultado.setText("NaN")
        else:
            num = float(num_str)
            cuadrado = num ** 2
            self.line_resultado.setText(round(str(cuadrado), 2))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventana = Ventana()
    ventana.show()
    app.exec_()
```

en este caso obtenemos el valor del `QLineEdit` cuando el botón se pulsa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otro ejemplo sin botón, enlazando la señal  `textEdited` del `QLineEdit` directamente:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ventana(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(317, 220)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)

        self.line_ingresar = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_ingresar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 113, 32))
        self.line_ingresar.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator())
        self.line_ingresar.textEdited.connect(self.calcular)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("² =", self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 20, 61, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.label.setFont(font)

        self.line_resultado = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_resultado.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 50, 113, 32))
        self.line_resultado.setReadOnly(True)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot() 
    def calcular(self):
        num_str = self.line_ingresar.text()
        if not num_str:
            self.line_resultado.setText("NaN")
        else:
            num = float(num_str)
            cuadrado = num ** 2
            self.line_resultado.setText(round(str(cuadrado), 2))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventana = Ventana()
    ventana.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver la clave está simplemente en obtener el texto y convertirlo a `float` en el momento que queremos obtener el número.

Comment: Gracias me fue de gran ayuda